# How to add content below woocommerce product gallery on specific product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add text below gallery to specific product. What I am missing?

[image]

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' , 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 5 );

function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery() {
global $product;
$id = $product->id;
if($id==3334){
    echo '<div class="text">';
    echo '<p>Random text</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a PHP error I think you need a last bracket "}" on the last line.

Also, you should add a class "woocommerce-product-gallery" to the div, in order to to inherit CSS float, read more here: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-content-below-the-single-product-page-images/

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing bracket `}`

Here is the correct code using latest woocommerce get function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' , 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 5 );

function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery() {
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();
    if($id==3334){
        echo '<div class="text">';
        echo '<p>Random text</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps